# Allow contributors to add limited number of a node

Tags: jahia

I want to allow my contributors to add a limited number of a node in Edit Mode. Here's what I have right now in my **definitions.cnd**:

```
[jnt:parent] > jnt:content, jmix:basicContent, mix:title
 - intro (string, richtext)
 + * (jnt:child)
```

This allows contributors to add as many node child they want. I want to limit that number to 2. I tried `+ 2 (jnt:child)` but that didn't change a thing.

How to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to specify how many child you want to add.

As workaround, it's possible to do that :

```
[jnt:parent] > jnt:content, jmix:basicContent, mix:title
 - intro (string, richtext)
 + firstChild (jnt:child)
 + secondChild (jnt:child)
```

Here, contributors would only be able to add these 2 node "child", with these names.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible in cnd.  Here is a link to the source docs: https://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/node-type-notation.html  It's either one or many.

The way I have controled that in the past is to use logic to in the ui to remove the option of adding additional nodes, and logic in the backing handlers to discard any attempts to add nodes.